# Host multiple versions of same app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I am creating a professional Android app but I am unsure on how to distribute it in the best way.

The app will be used by different customers. Each customer has its own server hosting the backend.

Now the problem is that for ugrading the backend the customer has to pay us a fee. So some users don't update because they don't need the new features. So these customers want to keep working with the old version of the app. And when they hire new employees they also want to be able to install the old version of the app.

Is it in any way possible to publish multiple versions of the same app in GooglePlay ?

So that users can install appV1, or appV2 or appV3 ? And that users for appV1 still receive bugfixes for appV1, ...

I know this is possible if I give each version a specific package name, but this is a problem for example when we solve a bug in appV1 and want to merge these changes into V2 and V3....

So in short : 'How to distribute multiple versions of the same app in Android ?'

Comment: You can't do it using the same package name